# Notifications Android

Tags: java, android

Well, I'm trying to use notifications, but this code doesn't work. I've tested it on 4.4 and 5.0. I can't understand, what is wrong.

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    Context context = getApplicationContext();

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

    Resources res = context.getResources();
    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(context);

    builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentTitle("Title")
            .setContentText("Text");

    Notification notification = builder.build();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);        
    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFY_ID, notification);
}
```

I'll be grateful for answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably because Google changes its notification API quite a lot in each Android Edition. So the API you used not compatible for multi Android version. But Google release appcompat-v7 \appcompat-v4 to solve this stuff.

Try the following code:

```
public void send(View v) {
    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, TestNotificationActivity.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    Notification notification = builder
            .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
            .setContentTitle("this is title")
            .setContentText("this is content")
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
            .build();
    manager.notify(NOTIFY_ID, notification);
}
```

Remember to import android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat.